# SQL Server - View a specific log entry in transaction log file (ldf)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ldf

This may have been asked before but I made a simple update to one column (varchar(max)) in a table and wanted to know if there is a simple way to look at the transaction log file (ldf) to see that specific update?  Can you possibly provide specific examples?

Comment: Having SQL profiler attached or a trace enabled may be an easier way to see what is happening on your server. I dont think you can get to the internals of MSSQL data files, or be able to understand them if you could.

Comment: Profiler is great for right now, but I'm looking to view past entries.  You may be right about not being able to view it, but this is why I'm asking if anyone knows how and can provide a solid example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can do that ie, you can view a specific entry in your transaction log. The best I can think of is to use:

```
Select * from ::fn_dblog(null,null)
```

You can also check:

- [How Do You Decode A Simple Entry in the Transaction Log?](http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/)
- [SQL Server fn_dblog() Function Details and Example](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/sql-server-dbcc-log-command-tl01/#.Vd9NV_mqqko)

Comment: Is there an intuitive way to read the binary on the Log Record?

Comment: @BenjSanders:- Just added few links. Hope that helps!

Comment: Slight modification:

Select top 10 * from ::fn_dblog(null,null)
Order By [Begin Time] DESC